# If $f$ is a continuous mapping of metric spaces $X$ into $Y$, prove that $f(\overline{E}) \subset \overline{f(E)}$ for all $E\subset X$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> If $f$ is a continious mapping of a metric space $X$ into a metric space $Y$, prove that $f(\overline{E}) \subset \overline{f(E)}$ for all $ E \subset X$

($\overline{E}$ denotes the closure of $E$)

---

This was a problem from Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Rudin.

Now my question is, if we take $E = X$, then $E'$ (the set of all limit points of $E$) will only be contained in $X$ if $X$ is closed. If $X$ is open, then we can easily show that the limit points of $E$ are not contained in $X$.

In that case that $X$ is open, we would have $f(a)$ undefined for all $a \in E'$, as $a \in E' \implies a \not\in X$, and thus $f(\overline{E})$ would be undefined for those $a \in E'$

Is there a misunderstanding on my part? $X$ surely can't be assumed to be closed.

$X$ would have to be  either

- closed
- or both open and closed (e.g. $\mathbb{R^2}$)

But $X$ can't just be open correct?

Comment: If $X$ is the ambient space, it is always a closed subset of itself, so that $X'$ is contained in $X$, this is: a space is always closed and open in itself.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, I've never heard of the term *'ambient space'* before, could you please clarify what you mean by that. Wikipedia has next to nothing on it

Comment: You have a set $X$ which is your metric space, and contains all other sets you're considering: it's the "ambient space". This space is always open and closed, because it contains **all** points you're looking at. If $(s_n)$ is a sequence of points in $X$ that converges to a point $s$ in $X$, then tautologically $X$ is closed (it contains the limit of all sequences that converge to  points in $X$). It is also open, because if $x\in X$, the open ball $B(x,1)$ is a subset  of $X$ (by the very definition of this ball), so $X$ contains an open ball around each of its points, and hence is open.

Answer (score 0):

$X$ is open and closed as every topological space.